# How to let header file know about class inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, header

I'm currently having this issue with inheritance:

`A.hpp`

```
{ 
    class Example;
}
```

`A.cpp`

```
{
    class Example : public Base {
       //OVERRIDE FUNCTIONS OF CLASS HERE
    }
}
```

`B.hpp`

```
{ 
    class DerivedExample;
}
```

`B.cpp`

```
{
    class DerivedExample : public Example {
       //How to override the functions of class Base here?
    }
}
```

And I have a method that receive a `Base` parameter:

`void doSomething(Base* base) = 0;`

The thing is, this `doSomething` method only accepts `Example` but does not accept `DerivedExample`. What do I have to do to let the header file of `A` know that class `Example` is a derived class of class `Base` without moving all method definitions there? Sorry if it sounds ambiguous, I'm pretty new to C++. Thank you.

Comment: Your class declarations should be in your header files.

Answer (score 1):

define the class in their respective hpp files and when you are writing the body of a function u have to define them as 
DerivedExample::doSomething() <- if this is a function ,
and u have to include the corresponding hpp file in the .cpp file 
if i understood ur qs correctly. then their wont be any ambiguity

iam attaching my sample addition multiple files program code.
similarly define your inherite class followed by the so called function.

```
header.hpp
#ifndef HEADER_HPP
#define HEADER_HPP
class Addition
{
public :
int sum(int a ,int b);
};
#endif


function.cpp
#include"header.hpp"
int Addition::sum(int a,int b)
{
//int a,b,result;
//result=a+b;
return a+b;
}

main.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include"header.hpp"
int main()
{
int a,b,result;
Addition add;
cout<<"enter the first number ";
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter the second number";
cin>>b;
result=add.sum(a,b);
cout<<"the sum of the two numbers is "<<result;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that but I can't move the method declaration (name and parameters) to the header file. This is a legacy project and lot of type parameters are not available in header, only in cpp file. I know I can move those types to header as well but there are too many of them, it would not worth the effort.